# How to fix the inner assignment in this case?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm working on my project and the last problem is here, how can I respect the InnerAssignmentCheck at line 3?

```
public void add(Account account) {
        if (tail == null) {
            head = tail = new Node(account, null);
        }
        else {
            tail.next = new Node(account, null);
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        size++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of `InnerAssignmentCheck` (my emphasis):

> Rationale: With the exception of for iterators, **all assignments should occur in their own toplevel statement** to increase readability.

Comment: Hmm... the JDK itself would fail this check thousands of times.